# How to disable the inputEl of a textfield in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working with ExtJS and I have a textfield component.
I would like to disable only the `inputEl` of a textfield component (not the label).

If I use the `setDisabled()` method of the textfield, then it sets disabled the `inputEl` but also the label.

I have used also the `setReadOnly()` method, but it does not grey out the `inputEl`, only set as `ReadOnly`.

Is there a way to disable only the `inputEl` of a textfield component?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set a custom class to the `disabledCls`

```
.ux-item-disabled .x-form-field, .ux-item-disabled .x-form-display-field, .ux-item-disabled .x-form-trigger {
   filter: alpha(opacity=30);
   opacity: .3;
}
```

see **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/Sj8zM/4/)**

Comment: yes, I have done the same approach and it works. But I thought it was a bit overkill and the textfield component should have that option as a method. Thanks for your help

Comment: @SergioKastro You're welcome :) I think the config option is the easiest way here to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
items: [{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  name: 'item',
  itemId: 'item',
  readOnly: true,
  listeners:{
    afterrender: function(f){
      c.inputEl.addCls('x-item-disabled');
    }
}]
```

You could even make it change dicamically if you include an if befor apply the class

Answer (score 0):

I have got another answer from the Sencha forum (I thought it may be interesting to post it here also)
 **Solution**:

Use the **setOpacity** method

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var panel =Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Basic Form',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Field',
        name: 'theField',
      disabled: true
    }]        
});

 panel.down('[xtype=textfield]').labelEl.setOpacity(1); });
```